# how to use a package button in visual force page standard controller

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

Hi have a custom button named Manage_Activities in Account, I want to use it in Account detail VF page, where I have written the page using standard controller.

Can I use command button functionality? If so, how to use the action function here.

The package is has a URL for the button: `/apex/Aspiro__ActivityManager?id={!Account.Id}`

Please help, how do I achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an `apex:commandButton`, example:

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="window.open('/apex/Aspiro__ActivityManager?id={!AccountId}','Aspiro Activity Manager','_blank');"/>
```

Comment: Of you can use URLFOR: {!URLFOR($Action.Account.~~API NAME OF BUTTON~~, account.id)}